# Why are my Heroku asset manifest files are blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm having a strange issue with Heroku. I'm trying to deploy a demo app on Cedar stack. It is a rails 3.2.x application. The app seems to be running but the assets manifests are empty and blank.

The javascript just has the manifest http://d.pr/i/2XWL
The css manifest doesn't have anything.. completely blank...

Here is the app on heroku if you want to check it out: http://fierce-thicket-5095.herokuapp.com/

Any help and direction is greatly appriciated.

Cheers

~k

Comment: do you have sprockets installed and working?

Comment: do you have asset pipeline on?

Comment: Yes, and yes. It works locally in production mode.. hmmm

Comment: Take a look on your assets, [css](http://fierce-thicket-5095.herokuapp.com/assets/application-fb6d11e0d2463d8275afb27b27746cd5.css) sprockets don't seems to be working, try to precompile your assets locally.

Comment: Well doing assets locally worked. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Ok, when you're pushing to heroku, did you see any errors? Also, did you try the assets locally on private navigation?